# Kill JVM not forcibly from command line in Windows 7

Tags: java, windows, cobertura

I have Cobertura instrumented jar running in JVM. When I press Ctrl-C in Windows console, where application runs, JVM ends and **Cobertura results are successfully flushed to cobertura.ser file**. But I need stop this JVM with command/tool (not Ctrl-C), something like "soft kill" in Linux ("kill" command without "-9" parameter). When I use "taskkill /PID 1234", it writes:

```
D:\>taskkill /PID 1234
ERROR: The process with PID 1234 could not be terminated.
Reason: This process can only be terminated forcefully (with /F option).
```

But when I use parameter /F, JVM is terminated forcibly and that is why **Cobertura results are not flushed to cobertura.ser file**.

How to kill JVM using Windows command/third party tool with successful Cobertura flush (windows "soft kill")?

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue. Did you get any fix for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try look at [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), using JavaScript or VBScript you create rules for selecting process and killing it.

For example http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/498-kill-a-process-using-wmi - enlist simple kill script using VBScript

Comment: @RadekJira, well may be let's totally shift a paradigm? Usually Cobertura is applied to unit test. Place to your test java invocation: `System.exit` - after execution during some time or on some condition.

Comment: You are true, best way is to change paradigm. We have very specific requirements and it will be better to change test-covering technology - for example JaCoCo, which uses on-the-fly instrumentation. Thanks for ideas.