# how to integrate SBT scala in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala

how to integrate SBT scala in eclipse? i am following this post as well as

i want to add existing project in scala. how to compile it and how to use build.sbt in eclipse?

[SBT integration test setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22041419/sbt-integration-test-setup)

and http://grosdim.blogspot.in/2013/01/quick-sbt-tutorial.html

but not finding any useful please help me

**how to compile and execute a existing project in eclipse using build.sbt??**

Comment: Can you explain what you have right now? an Eclipse project, a sbt project, something else... And what you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use build.sbt in Eclipse directly. Instead you need to generate an Eclipse project from your SBT project using [sbteclipse plugin](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse). Quoting the README:

- Add sbteclipse to your plugin definition file. You can use either:

  - the global file (for version 0.13 and up) at ~/.sbt/0.13/plugins/plugins.sbt
  - the project-specific file at PROJECT_DIR/project/plugins.sbt

    ```
    addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.4.0")
    ```
- In sbt use the command eclipse to create Eclipse project files

  ```
  > eclipse
  ```
- In Eclipse use the Import Wizard to import Existing Projects into Workspace

See the github wiki for more usage details. Don't forget to rerun `eclipse` command after changes in your SBT project.

Comment: after running sbt in command line i am getting >> Set current project to default-6c6f02 (in build file:/home/user_name/Videos/hello_scala/) and what to set and how please?? heere hello_scala is my project name